# Cordova SalesforceSDK - Icons & splash screens not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app, salesforce-ios-sdk

I am developing a hybrid android mobile application using Phonegap/Cordova and Salesforce mobile SDK. I am trying to change the icon and splash screen but it is not working as expected.

Reference Link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html

I have update my `config.xml` like below,

```
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />

        <icon src="icons/icon-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="icons/icon-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="icons/icon-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="icons/icon-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />

        <splash src="icons/screen-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

        <splash src="icons/screen-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="icons/screen-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    </platform>
```

When I emulate the application, the config.xml (in platforms/android/res/) is updating accordingly. But nothing seems to be working and I still see Salesforce icon which looks like below,

[image]

Any idea why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

When building for *Phonegap Build*, please use the [Phonegap Build Documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/) as much as possible.

If you are confused about the documentation, please ask on the [nitobi forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi). Some parts of the documentation are not up to date.

You want to read the [Documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/) -> Configuring -> [Icons and Splash Screens](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens) -> Default

Specifiably you want to add: `<icon src="icon.png" />` to your `config.xml`.

The documentation states:

> Default
>
> The default icon must be named icon.png and must reside in the root of your application folder.
>
> ```
> <icon src="icon.png" />
> ```

#### For the splashscreen,

make to use the new splashscreen plugin

[cordova-plugin-splashscreen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-splashscreen)

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to rename your icon image as 'sf__splash.png' and paste (replace with the original file of salesforce) in all the resources folders which are in `/plugins/com.salesforce/src/android/libs/SalesforceSDK/res/` folder.